# Content Security Policy: 'self' is blocking other included sources

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have these two inline script tags:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
```

- note: I tried specifying both the host only (https://apis.google.com) and the full URL.

And I added the following CSP header:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client">
```

This is supposed to allow me to include scripts from the origin and said two sources. However, I still receive the following error:

[image: csp errors]

Comment: Your mistake is trying to specify the full script URLs as allowed - that is wrong, you must specify the host only (plus optionally URL scheme and/or port number), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources#sources

Comment: I actually tried specifying the host only, which didn't work, and then I tried to specify the full URL.

Comment: Is it possible that your server / your system specifies a CSP via the HTTP header already? If so, that will take precedence over your `http-equiv` meta tag.

Comment: After doing some readings, I think the Google Chrome Extensions default CSP configuration is overriding mine. Any possible workarounds?

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow remote scripts so it ignores them in your CSP.

Comment: I think I just have to use a nonce.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that there are now two or more policies active. They can be defined in both meta tags and as response headers. Any content needs to pass all policies, and adding another policy can only make it stricter. One policy is "script-src 'self'" while your policy is "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js [https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"](https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client%22). Combined they will be equal to the first one. You need to figure out where the other policy is set and modify or disable it. It could be set by a framework, webserver, proxy, load balancer etc...